# Issue while extracting data using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

My objective is to convert an xls file to xlsx file.  The xls file which I am trying to convert is actually an html file containing tables (This xls file is obtained as a result of a query from jira). To facilitate the conversion I have created a file handler and then given that file handler to a beautiful soup and have extracted the table on interest and this extracted table is converted to a string and given to pandas dataframe for further processing.

This works fine but when the file size is large say around 80 MB it takes a large amount of time to process. How do I overcome this?

```
    import bs4, os
    import pandas as pd


    print('Begin')
    fileName = 'TestSample.xls'
    fileHandler=open(fileName, encoding='utf-8')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(fileHandler,'html.parser')
    tbl = soup.find_all('table', id='issuetable')
    df=pd.read_html(str(tbl))
    df[0].to_excel("restult.xlsx", index=False)
    print('Completed')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way for large files, but you can try different ways.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
print('Begin')
fileName = 'TestSample.xls'
html=open(fileName, encoding='utf-8').read()
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
start = 0 # If a string can uniquely mark the starting position of data, the performance will be better
tbl = doc.getElement('table', attr='id',value='issuetable', start=start)
print(tbl.outerHtml)
```

## Or block read

```
f=open(fileName, encoding='utf-8')
html = ''
start = '' # Start of block
end = '' # End of block
for line in f.readlines():
    if not html:
        html+=line
        if line.find(end)>=0:
            break
    elif line.find(start)>=0:
        html = line
        if line.find(end)>=0:
            break
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
tbl = doc.getElement('table', attr='id',value='issuetable')
print(tbl.outerHtml)
```

Comment: In Java to read large file we use BufferedReader, this helps in accomplishing the task faster and also avoid out of Memory Exceptions.